# How to generate huge numbers of random numbers at runtime in spark with immutable dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a problem where I need to generate millions of unique random numbers for an application running in spark. Since dataframes are immutable, everytime I add a generated number, I do a union to the existing dataframe which in turn creates a new dataframe. With millions of numbers required, this might cause performance issues. Is there any mutable data structure that can be used for this requirement

I have tried with dataframes doing a union with the existing dataframe

Comment: You could give a try to monotonicallyIncreasingId function (org.apache.spark.sql.functions.monotonicallyIncreasingId). I think it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to generate a dataframe  having millions of unique random numbers.

```
    import scala.util.Random
    val df = Random.shuffle((1 to 1000000)).toDF
    df.show(20)
```

Have tried generating a dataframe with 1 million unique random numbers and it hardly took 1-2 seconds.

```
+------+
| value|
+------+
|204913|
|882174|
|407676|
|913166|
|236148|
|788069|
|176180|
|819827|
|779280|
| 63172|
|  3797|
|962902|
|775383|
|583273|
|172932|
|429650|
|225793|
|849386|
|403140|
|622971|
+------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

The dataframe that I created looked something like this. Hope this would cater to your requirement.

Comment: have edited the answer to generate unique random numbers.